# Please Check My Fictional Calculus (Halting Problem, Incompleteness)

Tags: hard-science, mathematics

For a story, I'm having a character invent a new kind of calculus.

### Halting Problem

The new math efficiently solves the Halting Problem.

What is the Halting Problem?

Provided you have code like this --

> x = input(); while (x <> 0) { x = input(); }

How many cycles will it take for this code to stop running? The answer that's obvious to a human is that this will run until the user input is = 0

And that's what the new fictional calculus will provide as an answer -- that this will run until x is zero.

### The Barber Paradox

The new match also efficiently solves the Barber Paradox.

What is the Barber Paradox?

> A law requires all the men in the town to be shaved (A). All of the men who do not shave themselves (B) must be shaved by the town barber. Who shaves the town barber?

Like the Halting Problem, the answer is obvious to people, but hard to encode mathematically -- which is what this fictional calculus does. Either the assumption that the town barber is a member of set A is mistaken (maybe the barber is a woman, maybe the law has an exception for the town barber), or the proposed rule of set B is incomplete. More information is required to answer the question -- and that's the answer in this fictional calculus.

### Use Case

This math is intended to be simplified to the point where the results above are as simple as $\lim_{ x \to 0 } {{\sin{x}} \over x} = 1 $. Individuals can solve extremely complicated problems on a piece of paper, much like real calculus enabled folks to look at  dynamic systems of all kinds. The exact formalism doesn't matter.

The use case is that characters will be able to rapidly evaluate engineering conditions in extreme environments (like Venus, for example). Provided a set of our assumed relationships and actual test results, the mathematician identifies where an assumed relationship is incomplete, and either -- identifies precisely what the mis-assumption is (the barber is a woman; x will equal 0 in 30 seconds), a variable that stands-in for the incomplete part, or at least that the incomplete part exists. Hopefully, very quickly replacing the trial-and-error of years of turning over rocks and trying things out with a few weeks of things that can be done with a probe.

### The Question

So, my question is this -- does this make sense? Does the use case make sense? Most importantly -- is this a kind of math that already exists, and I just didn't know about it? I see that there are similarities to the Halting Problem example and [Big O notation](https://infogalactic.com/info/Big_O_notation), specifically.

Comment: I think you've rather misunderstood the halting problem. To begin with, it only states that *some* programs cannot be decided, not all or even most. (And properly speaking, it doesn't include programs that take user input; it only comments on the program itself and the memory state of the computer running it, not on anything a user might or might not do. An impatient user with Ctrl-C can guarantee any program "halts" within 10 seconds but this, sadly, does not count.)

Comment: Are you aware that it's been proven that there isn't an algorithm or equation that can say for any program whether it will halt or not?

Comment: Computer logic relies on a program/subroutine to decide the output is either true or false, halting problem highlights a flaw that certain program/subroutine can itself be contradictory and the output is indecisive (unsolvable). So there you go it is not a math problem although you had to use math to make the argument... See what I just did there ;D

Comment: What does "x <> 0" mean?

Comment: @Daron “<>” is a sql operator meaning “does not equal”. It might also be that in other languages but it is definitely that in SQL.

Comment: Please check my fictional calculus . . . of which I won't tell you anything.

Comment: @alexp - that’s disappointing. The question feels well-framed.

Comment: @alexp - so that I know better for next time, what kind of description were you looking for?

Comment: @daron not equal to.

Comment: I don't know, it is a *new* calculus... For example, take your first problem, which you mistakenly call the "halting" problem (it is not **the** halting problem, it is a straightforward application of reasoning about programs); we do have, for real, mathematical frameworks for [reasoning about programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctness_(computer_science)): what does the new calculus do which the existing frameworks don't? The second problem is very easily represented in first order predicate logic; what does the new calculus do which plain ordinary first order predicate logic doesn't?

Comment: your "new calculus" is basically mathematical magic, conflicting with already proven statements. (also: with the _precise wording_ used, your barber paradox is technically _not_ a paradox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't check your fictional calculus because you didn't provide us with it.  However, we can look at your descriptions.

The halting problem example gives a fair bit of insight into what you seek.  There is no solution to the halting problem as defined by mathematicians.  The language used to describe the halting problem formally includes the limitations of the language used to act upon it.

Likewise, the shaving of the barber has a well understood set of translations into set theory, and those formal definitions offer no opportunities to break free with a new form of calculus.  Just as we will never find a calculus that proves 2 + 1 = 1, we will never find a calculus which resolves the issues arising in the formal language description of these problems.

Of course, I keep throwing around this phrase, "formal language."  You've given us an English gloss of several problems which cause mathematicians' hair to stand on end.  But the English version isn't so bad.  You yourself point out the loopholes that might resolve the barber problem.

To that end, I'd like to point out the halting problem's big brother: [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).  You're welcome to follow the link to read the formal language version of the theorem, but the English gloss will be sufficient here.  Rice's theorem states that *all* non-trivial semantic properties of any algorithm are undecidable.  In this sense, "semantic" means it's referring to what the algorithm does, as opposed to "syntactic" properties which simply refer to the content of the algorithm (such as "does it have a if-then branch?").  And non-trivial just means that the property is true for some algorithms and false for others.  Its trivial to prove that an algorithm "either halts or does not halt," because all programs do that.

I call Rice's Theorem the "big brother" to the halting problem because the halting problem is just one specific instance.  If your property is "does the program terminate," Rice's Theorem becomes the halting problem.  But Rice's theorem points to the key thing your calculus looks to be working towards: semantics.  Your calculus needs to operate on the semantic meaning of these phrases, not just its syntax.  For example, the issue with the Barber is a non-issue in semantics because the loopholes are rather explicit.

How explicit?  Well, you talked of wanting to know if there was an existing caluclus for this.  There are.  There are several, because semantics is a big deal.  Now none of them claim to be "complete," but they all have their places.  The most calculus-y one I can think of are the [Description Logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic) (DL).  These are semantic tools which are designed to permit "turn the crank" style approaches to arrive at answers.  For example, the barber problem can be rendered in a language, [OWL](https://www.w3.org/OWL/)*:

```
# The class of men is a subset of the class of shaved things
SubClassOf(Man Shaved) 

# Everyone who is shaved is shaved by the barber.
EquivalentClasses(Shaved ObjectHasValue(shavedBy theBarber)) 

# Nobody shaves themselves
IrreflexiveObjectProperty(shavedBy)

# the person we seek is the person who shaves the barber
ObjectPropertyAssertion(shavedBy theBarber thePersonWeSeek)
```

Within this construct, we can ask "is this satisfiable?"  Is it theoretically possible to assign values to `thePersonWeSeek` such that all of the criteria are met?  And the answer is yes.  By the inference rules of OWL, we can determine that this system works.  Now, of course, one way is to consider that the class "Man" has 0 elements in it -- no men in the town!  To fix that,

```
# Assert that there is at least one person (someone) who is a man
ClassAssertion(Man someone)
```

Now, with that loophole closed, we find that yes, it is *still* satisfiable.  We can even make statements about theBarber, such as `ClassAssertion(ObjectComplement(Man) theBarber)`, which is the loophole you mentioned -- the barber isn't a man (the barer is a member of the complement of the class "Man").

This resolves your use case rather cleanly.  Depending on *how* you translate the English phrases into OWL, you'll find different loop holes, or you might even find that you closed the loophole and the entire system is considered "unsatisfiable."  For example, if you add rules that a barber is a human, and that all humans are men or women, you would be able to deduce that the barber is a woman.

Likewise, your goal of sidestepping the halting problem is supported by DL  as well.  If you can *describe* a program semantically, you can sometimes manipulate that to arrive at the answer you seek.  This is what optimizing compilers do.  They find a way to describe your program that lets them make useful statements.

Now DL is *absolutely* not a panacea. It doesn't rewrite mathematics.  DLs were carefully designed to be quite powerful semantic tools, but to always be *decidable*.  If you turn the crank on any consistency query you might make on a DL system, you can always find an answer.  There's no undecidability here.  How do they do it?  Well they are intentionally weakened to sidestep the sorts of issues here.  They can't actually describe Turing machines sufficiently to put together the phrase "does this Turing machine halt?"  They do this by eschewing counting (amongst other brilliant little choices).  You can't do [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) in them, because they have no way to notate `n+1` in a way that permits proving anything.

But I do believe they are as close to a "calculus" to answer your kinds of questions as I have come across.  They're fascinating beasts too.  Looking up from this nice easy calculus into the larger world of semantics, there is [Model Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory), where we say "given this set of true statements in our Model, what other true statements can we make?"  The rule of Description Logics closely follow the concepts of entailment of Model Theory, they just operate on a particular language which has nice properties.  You can do Model Theory with the English phrases, without translating it into OWL.  It's just harder to really get anywhere when your sentences are in a natural language.  [Category Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) may help with that.  There are some who investigate category theory who claim it is the fundamental basis of language: all natural language phrasings can be transformed into the language of categories.  A daunting claim indeed!

So, reading between the lines a great deal, your caluclus is probably a calculus of semantics.  And, because you seek to make some proofs easy, it probably has an easy core of something like DL which is decidable.  But, if you want to keep it fictional, it should trampoline off of this decidable DL core into something more magical.  Something like [psychohistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_(fictional)), a fictional statistical calculus that Asimov used to build a character that predicted the course of all of humanity for thousands of years.

---

* I use OWL, rather than the native language of DL, because its a bit more accessable.  DL is full of terse exacting symbology.  It might look like:
$$M\sqsubseteq S$$
$$\forall_{p, q} (p, q): s \to (q = b)$$
$$\forall_{p, q} (p, q): s \to (p \ne q)$$
$$(b, x): s$$

While this is a very well defined notation, I find this is harder to read with all the symbols.  The words used in OWL seem to help.  If you're interested in the connection, the dialect of OWL I am using, OWL-DL is a ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {SHOIN}}^{\mathcal {(D)}}}$ language, where that mess of mathcal capital letters describes a particular kind of Description Logic.  It happens to be one that has received a great deal of attention thanks to OWL's success.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged this as hard-science:
**No, it does not make sense.** There is proof for the halting problem. Not that difficult of a proof to follow either if I recall correctly.

If you are trying to set up a hard science everything is the same, but this one thing is different. That's cool, but just hand wave the details. Lamp shade it without technobabble, carry on with the story. Just make sure readers understand the limits of the tool else you might run into problem of 'a wizard did it'.

If you must have some plausible technobabble you would be better off saying something like he "has proof that np==p."(Which we don't currently have proof for). Which would decrease solve time of many difficult problems. Which seems to be what you are after.

Better still just say your protagonists have better computers with some strong AI assistants. More plausible, similar affect. Doesn't hint at breaking proven theorems.

Comment: I agree. The first two examples sound like gobbledygook and the Use Case is too vague to answer whether this sort of maths already exists or not.

Comment: The halting problem proof (informally) goes like: If you have a algorithm that solves the halting problem you can make an algorithm that goes into an infinite loop if the given input halts and stops if the given input does not halt. Then you give it itself as input and have a paradox. If it halts it doesn't halt and if it doesn't halt it halts.